# how to connect a Blazor app to api server

Tags: api, blazor

Im pretty new on Blazor, I have a request to create a Blazor app to read and write to an from a database on our server, I can get the blazor app to work just fine by adding the connectingstring to the appsettings.json file, my issue now is that my boss wants to use the blazor app to talk to the database thru an API only, no database connection at all, how do I connect my blazor app to the server API to read data or how do I set up the connection to the server API?... PLEASE HELPPPPPP thank you

This is my connectingstring on the appsettings.json file that works fine but I need to connect to the API on the server:

```
DBConnection: "Data Source="****";Database="****";Integrated Security=true;"
```

Comment: Have a look at the documentation on [how to create an api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio). The idea is the blazor app talks to the api, and the api will talk to the database.

Comment: Not entirely clear. Blazor WebAssembly requires an API anyway, for Blazor server it's an option. Both can easily consume a REST API, you will have to be much more specific.

Comment: Please create a new Blazor project using the the default visual studio template and you see how the client app consumes an whether API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a new Blazor WebAssembly app and tick the "asp.net core hosted" checkbox, you'll see the client calls a weather API on the server.